# Expression query in PHP

Tags: php

I am very new to PHP and MYSQL but can use access to some degree.
I have two tables, one with the field Price and the other with the field Exchange.
All I want to do is show the results as an array in a HTML table of Price x Exchange.
The expression in Access is as follows:

```
`SELECT tbmetal.[Price GBP], tbexchange.Rate, [Price GBP]*[Rate]/100 AS Ex
FROM tbexchange, tbmetal;
```

This is how pathetic I am as far as PHP is concerned:

```
$con= mysql_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass);
@mysql_select_db($dbname) or die( "Unable to select database");

//retrieve data
$result = mysql_query( "SELECT * FROM tbmetal,tbexchange");




//Simple GBP to USD Conversion Calculator
//define constants:
define("GBP_TO_USD", 0.6);
//enter GBP
$GBP = 12;
//convert to USD, multiply by constant
$UDS = $GBP * GBP_TO_USD;


echo 
"<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th width='200px'>Metal</th>
<th width= '100px'>Price Per Gram GBP</th>
<th width= '100px'>Price Per Gram USD</th>
<th width= '100px'>Price Per Gram EUR</th>
</tr>";

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
   {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['Metal'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['Price'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $UDS . "</td>"
    echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";

?>
```

Comment: Please post the table/column structures of those two tables. Since your query has no condition joining them, MySQL will return all rows from the first multipled by all rows from the second (cartesian product)

Answer (score 0):

Please specify what is the problem that you occured.
Here you can find the documentation http://www.php.net/mysql_query ,but please take note that `mysql_query` is deprecated and you should use `mysqli_query` ( http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php ) or `PDO` ( http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php ) which are safer against SQL Injection

Answer (score 0):

Basically, what you can do is pull the data out of the table as you've done in access only you need a way to relate the two tables together.  In the example below, I've hinged both tables together on the `Metal` field occurring in both tables.  Now, I do not know if you have a `Metal` field in both tables since you did not provide that information, but if not, find something that does tie the two tables together and use that.

Here is an example.

```
<?php

// CONNECT TO THE DATABASE
$con = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);


// SET THE DEFAULT EXCHANGE RATES
define("GBP_TO_USD", 0.6);
define("GBP_TO_EURO", 1.2);


// BUILD THE QUERY
$sql = "SELECT tbmetal.Price, tbexchange.Rate FROM tbexchange, tbmetal WHERE tbmetal.Metal = tbexchange.Metal";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die("Cannot get metal prices");


// START PRINTING OUT THE TABLE    
echo "
        <table border='1'>
        <tr>
          <th width='200px'>Metal</th>
          <th width= '100px'>Price Per Gram GBP</th>
          <th width= '100px'>Price Per Gram USD</th>
          <th width= '100px'>Price Per Gram EUR</th>
        </tr>";

// LOOP THROUGH THE RESULTS FROM THE QUERY, DO THE CONVERSION AND OUTPUT THE TABLE ROW
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

    $GBP = $row['Price']; //enter GBP

    $UDS = $GBP * GBP_TO_USD; //convert to USD, multiply by constant
    $EUROS = $GBP * GBP_TO_EURO; //convert to EURO, multiply by constant


    // PRINT OUT THE TABLE ROW
    echo "
        <tr>
          <td>".$row['Metal']."</td>
          <td>".$GBP."</td>
          <td>".$UDS."</td>
          <td>".$EUROS."</td>
        </tr>";

}

// CLOSE THE TABLE 
echo "
        </table>";
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I used metals and it works fine. I will eventually get the hang of this :)